# Ipad XML parsing doubts

Tags: ipad

my requirement is parse an xml file and display it in ipad.But i was totally confused how to parse this xml file,i am novice in xml parsing. kindly help me how to create array for it and how to display in ipad.Its a magazine  news application ,any source code or sample applicatiom may help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in XML parsing class in iOS called `NSXMLParser`.  As an `init` parameter it takes an `NSData` that is usually the data you get back from a web service.  Assign  yourself as its delegate and call `[parser parse]` and it will call your delegate when it encounters an element, when it finishes an element, etc.  See documentation for the [parser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSXMLParser) and its [delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate).

If you have control over the structure of your XML, I've found it easier when it's structured like this:

```
<Element attr1='value1' attr2='value2' />
```

instead of:

```
<Element>
  <attr1>value1</attr1>
  <attr2>value2</attr2>
</Element>
```

The reason is that the callback for when it finds an element is:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

where `attributes` is a dictionary of the values, so in the above example, `[attributes objectForKey:@"attr1"]` would give you "value1" if it was structured in the first way.  If it's the second way, you end up doing lots of state management that's a bit of a pain, especially if you've got elements within elements, etc.

In addition to `NSXMLParser` thare are open-source parsers that either do everything themselves or wrap the built-in parser.  I've written my own wrapper for it before.  See [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) for a post on the subject (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181690/choosing-the-right-ios-xml-parser) for the link).

Comment: thankzz   http://listlinkz.com/xml/1.php.this is the link that i have to do in ipad.i cannot split these components to array