# How To Parse XML in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I am Trying To Use NSXMLParser to parse an xml file using cocoa which goes like this..

```
<UserDetails>
<Name>John Doe</Name>
<UserName>jdoe</UserName>
<Password>supersecretpass</Password>
</UserDetails>
```

Now i am using the method as follows:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"MEthod came here");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {

        NSLog(@"Name :");
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the values contained in the *elementName* tag. How do i do it..The method is being called but i am unable to retrieve the value contained within the tag values of XML.

Comment: You should have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181690/choosing-the-right-ios-xml-parser

Comment: i did..but the question is about which parser to select..i am working with NSXMLParser..i need to know how to retrieve the values from XML Elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value enclosed within tags by *intelligently* using this delegate method ;):

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

This link can prove to be useful - [`Handling XML Elements and Attributes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-1001887)

Comment: okay..so how would I know the value of which element is being retrieved??