# XML parsing in objective-c under IOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xml-parsing

I am newbie to IOS application development.

I have to parse an XML document now and as I see IOS 5 provides NSXMLParser, that enables to parse XML documents in an event driven way by delegates. Isn't there a 'normal' -DOM- way of XML parsing for this platform? I'd like to make a simple method, that inputs a very simple XML as string and gives back a string that is calculated from the data can be found in the input XML.I don't need this delegating thing now, it just make my life harder, I don't wanna anything out of my method, event handlers etc.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181690/choosing-the-right-ios-xml-parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simpler library called TBXML - http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html