# How do I populate a sectioned table from a xml file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Let's say I have an XML-file looking like this:

```
<messages>
  <message id="1">
    <text>Hello</text>
    <text>How are you?</text>
    <from>Mr. Nice</from>
  </message>
  <message id="1">
    <text>Howdy</text>
    <text>What's up?</text>
    <from>Mrs. Nice</from>
  </message>
</messages>
```

How do I then populate a sectioned table like this:

HEADER 1 = Mr.Nice

TABLECELL 1.1 = Hello,
TABLECELL 1.2 = How are you?

HEADER 2 = Mrs.Nice

TABLECELL 2.1 = Howdy,
TABLECELL 2.2 = What's up?

Thanks in advance!

// Sebastian

Comment: Currently I'm using objectAtIndex:indexPath.row, but as the next section comes along the row will restart at 0, which I'm not certain how to fix.

Comment: Please update your question with details on how you have parsed your XML into array(s) to use as a datasource - it sounds like your problem is either in your data source methods or the way you have parsed the XML. Do you want one section per `message` element or to group all messages from the same person under one section?

Answer (score 0):

To parse your xml into something useful to your app, say, by populating a collection of objects, you will need to start with [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

To understand how NSXMLParser applies to your situation, [here is a fantastic tutorial](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) describing how to use it with an XML file.

Comment: Well. I have everything set up and it's working, most of it. Though the second table has the same tablecell values as the first one.

Comment: See also this post regarding selecting the right parser for the job: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181690/choosing-the-right-ios-xml-parser. The "How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project" link is excellent.

Comment: @Vin my apologies.  I've updated my answer to fix the link. Thanks!